# How can I create a new column in a dataframe based on permutations of other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    var1   var2   var3   var4  
a   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
b   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
c   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
d   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
e   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
f   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
```

I want to create a new column which assigns `a` to `f` to categories based on what permutation of `TRUE` and `FALSE` each has for the variables along the top.

In this simplified example, the result would look like:

```
    var1   var2   var3   var4    category
a   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE      A
b   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE      B
c   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE       C
d   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE      D
e   TRUE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE      A
f   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE       C
```

Notice that each unique permutation of `TRUE` and `FALSE` becomes a different category, and since `a` and `e` have the same permutation, they end up in the same category (`A`).

Is there an easy way to do this, which can work if there is a large number of variables along the top, and potentially not limited to `TRUE` and `FALSE` but also if the dataframe was filled with categories/numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```
## paste the rows together, creating a character vector
x <- do.call(paste, df)
## match it against itself and apply to 'LETTERS', and assign as new column
df$category <- LETTERS[match(x, x)]
df
#    var1  var2  var3  var4 category
# a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE        A
# b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE        B
# c FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE        C
# d  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE        D
# e  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE        A
# f FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE        C
```

The above code can be written as a one-liner if we use a named list as an environment.  This avoids making any new assignments to the global environment.

```
df$category <- LETTERS[with(list(x = do.call(paste, df)), match(x, x))]
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 
    var2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), var3 = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), var4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", 
"var4"), row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Accepted. A nice and elegant answer that I've been able to modify for my own needs

Comment: `LETTERS[with(list(x = interaction(df)), match(x, x))]` as a slight simplification.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Example DATA
mydata = structure(list(V1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 
V2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), V3 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), V4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))

#RUN THE ONE LINER (Incorporating David Arenburg's advice in comment)
mydata$category = toupper(letters[as.numeric(as.factor(do.call(paste, mydata)))])
```

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(do.call(paste, df)))` a bit more general

Comment: Your result is not in the order desired by OP

Comment: `LETTERS[interaction(df, drop=TRUE)]` if the order of the letters doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea that might come in handy to avoid coercing to "character"s. (The "data.frame" `df` is from RichScriven's answer.)

Order data:

```
o = do.call(order, df)
```

And for each *ordered* column, find out whether the next element is different or not to its previous:

```
starts_new_elt = lapply(df, function(x) { 
                                 xo = x[o]
                                 c(TRUE, xo[-1] != xo[-length(x)]) 
                             })
```

This returns a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` where, for each position, specifies whether is the same or not to its previous element. Having that, we can get a similar vector of whether a row, in the *ordered* "data.frame", is the same or not to its previous:

```
starts_new_row = Reduce("|", starts_new_elt)
```

Comparing this vector with the ordered "data.frame" we note that there is a `TRUE` whenever a row is different to its previous and a `FALSE` otherwise.

```
starts_new_row
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

df[o, ]
#   var1  var2  var3  var4
#c FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#f FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#d  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#e  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Finally, using `cumsum` on this vector returns an id for each grouped row in the *ordered* "data.frame", which can be re-ordered by `order(o)`:

```
gr = cumsum(starts_new_row)[order(o)]
gr
#[1] 3 4 1 2 3 1
```

For the exact output, we can use:

```
LETTERS[match(gr, unique(gr))]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "A" "C"
```

A handy alternative of the above is based on the function `grouping` that was added to newer versions of R off the "data.table" package. `grouping` returns the ordering, as before, but some convenient attributes, too:

```
o2 = do.call(grouping, df)
ends = attr(o2, "ends")
gr2 = rep(seq_along(ends), c(ends[1], diff(ends)))[order(o2)]

gr2
#[1] 3 4 1 2 3 1
LETTERS[match(gr2, unique(gr2))]
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "A" "C"
```